How to obtain the names of only the affected columns after an update operation in GridDB?
I am performing an update operation on a GridDB container involving multiple columns. I update 10 columns, but only 2 of them are actually modified (the values of the other columns remain unchanged). For logging purposes, I need to identify which columns were updated.
I am using GridDB’s APIs to execute the update operation, similar to:
container.put(row);

After executing the update, I know that the number of affected rows can be tracked, but I need to log:

The actual data that was updated.
The names of the specific
columns that were modified.

